# How bind data to multiple nested components in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, nested, components

In Angular 4 app using following structure:
[image]

ComponentA get folowing model from service:

```
class ViewModel {
    public someBool: boolean;                
    public someNumber: number;               
    public someArray: CFlightClassQuote[];   
    public someOtherNumber: number;               
    public someString: string; 
}
```

ComponentA class:

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  searchResult: Array<ViewModel>;

  constructor(private searchResultService: SearchResultService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchResultService.getSearchResultTable('hash').then( result => {
      this.searchResult = result;
    });
  }
}
```

ComponentA tempate:

```
*some html*
    <div>
      <app-component-b [dataSet]="searchResult"></app-component-b>
    </div>
*some html*
```

In componentB i'm using *ngFor

ComponentB template:

```
<div class="results-table" *ngFor="let item of dataSet">
   <span>{{item.someString}}</span>
   <app-component-c [dataSet]="item.SomeArray"></<app-component-c>

another html
</div>
```

ComponentB class:

```
export class ComponentB implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataSet: Array<ViewModel>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Data was correctly binding for ComponentB but ComponentC still empty.
I think that i'm wrong in this string:

```
<app-component-c [dataSet]="item.SomeArray"></<app-component-c>
```

And data should be passed into the ComponentC like in case with ComponentA and ComponentB.

How should this be done correctly?

Comment: can u create a plunker to reproduce the issue? also add all templates HTML to post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is correct in its spelling and also assuming your component C is defined similar to component B but referring to the right array-type (`CFlightClassQuote`), there is a typo in your template when you access the property referring to the array.

This,

```
<app-component-c [dataSet]="item.SomeArray"></<app-component-c>
```

should be,

```
<app-component-c [dataSet]="item.someArray"></<app-component-c>
                                ^^^
                                here
```

Comment: We just pass dataSet in component c's ts file as in input correct?